# How to tell whether Firefox window is private or not?

Tags: firefox, user-interface, private-browsing

I use Firefox 22.0 and sometimes I select "New Private Window" option from the file menu. I cannot distinguish between private window and the normal window. They both look the same.

In Chrome, when you select Incognito mode you can see a person with hat spying on the window top left corner. Is there such a notification for Firefox rather than remembering?

Answer (score 2):

From the Firefox knowledgebase (at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info)

At the window title it should show Private Browsing and a mask icon.

[image: distinguish between normal and private window]

Comment: Note that this does not help if windows are minimized to the notification area of the system tray and only their icons are visible - normal and private windows use the same icon.

Answer (score 1):

And if you are using a Linux distribution, the first tab will have the mask but the mask won't be there if you have closed it and are using newer tabs. But there should always be '**(Private Browsing)**' on the window title.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKjörling for posting the picture. I wasn't able to post the picture

Comment: Might I add that this also applies to Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

As of Mozilla Firefox 48.0.2, the only way I found to distinguish between private window and normal window, after closing the "Private Browsing" tab, is by visiting the `File` menu in menu bar.

For normal window, there is a `New Window` menu item under `File` menu.

For private window, the `New Window` menu item is missing under `File` menu.

Refer to the image below for your reference:

[image]